# If we remove finite number of elements from a dense subset, will it be still dense?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $D$ be a dense susbet of $X$. If we remove a finite number of elements from $D$, will it still be dense in $X$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take a finite topological space!

Comment: Yes, or take an infinite topological space with one dense point...

Comment: But what about $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. If we remove a finite subset from $\mathbb{Q}$ will it still be dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @luka5z : Of course!

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is Hausdorff and has no isolated points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such spaces which are counter examples do appear for instance in algebraic geometry. The spectrum of a integral domain equipped with the Zariski topology satisfies $\overline {\{ (0) \}} = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$, so of course if I remove the single element of this set I get the empty set.

You probably have in mind analysis examples, so maybe if you assume some extra properties on your topological space, you'll have such a property. Depending on what you have a proof may be possible.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

Assume $X$ to be Hausdorff. Since $D$ is dense in $X$, every point of $X$ is either in $D$ or a limit point of $D$.

Suppose $x \in X$ is a limit point of $D$. Since every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $D$ in infinitely many points, removing finitely many points from $D$ doesn't affect this.

Now, if $x$ is a point in $D$ but not a limit point of $D$, then  $D \setminus \{x\}$ is not dense in $X$.

Even in the non-Hausdorff spaces, it need not remain dense after removal of a finite set.